# Change dbpath in mongoexport. Using dbpath shows :dbexit and exports 0 record

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoexport

I am trying to export a **JSON** file from **mongoDB**. If I do not use the --dbpath option, the records are exporting. 
However if i use dbpath, it shows as:

C:\mongodb\bin>mongoexport --db aman --collection saved --dbpath D: --out aman.json
exported 0 records

```
2015-02-02T20:32:37.922+0530 [tools] dbexit:
2015-02-02T20:32:37.925+0530 [tools] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-02-02T20:32:37.925+0530 [tools] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-02-02T20:32:37.927+0530 [tools] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-02-02T20:32:37.927+0530 [tools] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2015-02-02T20:32:37.928+0530 [tools] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-02-02T20:32:37.929+0530 [tools] closeAllFiles() finished
2015-02-02T20:32:37.930+0530 [tools] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2015-02-02T20:32:37.930+0530 [tools] dbexit: really exiting now
```

Comment: Why are you specifying the --dbpath option? The --dbpath is used to attach to database when not running mongod..

Comment: I need to move the json file to some specific location. How can i do it?

Comment: Please try specifying the full path on the `--out`.